# Graph Theory : trees, degrees and paths.

Tags: graph-theory

Justify that a tree with $n$ vertices that has a vertex of degree $k\gt 2$, hasn't got a path with length bigger than $n-k + 2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Every path in a tree contains at most $2$ edges from a vertex and there are exactly $n-1$ edge in each tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the base case for the smallest n and k, then building out more complex trees from there.

Comment: I think this is more appropriate as a comment.